# How to perform bitwise operations between single-precision floating point vectors on ARMv7?

Tags: c++, optimization, assembly, arm, simd

I would like to write SIMD versions of bitwise logical operations on ARMv7 such that

```
static inline float32x4_t operator ^ (float32x4_t const & a, float32x4_t const & b)
```

. Since ARM has no instruction for this as Intel does, what is the correct way to implement this operation?

Comment: Cast to a corresponding vector type and use a xor (eor in arm-speak) instruction on it?

Comment: "Since ARM has no instruction for this..." Er, what do you think `vand`, `vorr`, and `veor` are there for?

Comment: @Notlikethat Those or for integer types not float (http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491h/CIHJBEFE.html )

Comment: But you have vreinterpret* intrinsics.

Comment: So, as Marc says, cast the vector to a different 32-bit element type that _is_ accommodated by an intrinsic. Have a think about why types don't actually matter for a _bitwise_ operation (and thus why the underlying bitwise NEON instructions don't even encode the element size, let alone the type, only the total vector width)

Comment: Bitwise operations generally only make sense for integers, not floating point. What is the logical result of `1.0 ^ 2.0`?

Comment: `vreinterpretq_f32_u32(veorq_u32(vreinterpretq_u32_f32(a),vreinterpretq_u32_f32(b)))`

Comment: @MarkRansom Bitwise ops on floating point make sense to manipulate the sign bit. abs, neg, neg(abs), copysign, etc can be expressed as bit ops with a constant.

Comment: Come to think of it, it's exactly the same as the scalar case - in both C and C++ the bitwise operations are only defined for integral types (and in C at least, only fully-defined for _unsigned_ types) so if you already have scalar code you must have some kind of casting of floats there to take inspiration from.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I guess I wasn't clear in my comment. What I meant is that it makes no sense to talk about bitwise operations on the floating point values themselves, but the bit representations are most clearly expressed as integers. Using integer instructions on a bit pattern, even if the bit pattern represents a floating point number, should just come naturally.

Comment: @MarkRansom Is it wise to represent raw memory content as int array in C++? Or is it guaranteed to work in compilers that follow strict-aliasing rules in optimization. The only legal way to inspect memory content in C++ might be  by reinterpreting it as an array of [signed/unsigned] char.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you want to be completely standard compliant expect to throw all the tricks out the door. `memcpy()` would be the only way to go. That said, when you get to the point of needing bitwise operations on floating-point, it's probably because you care about performance. And you probably care enough to use non-standard tricks like union type-punning, reinterpret casts, compiler intrinsics. (On x86, there are dedicated floating-point bitwse instructions exposed through intrinsics.)